# async / await looping through array of to get s3 signed URL's

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I've written the following code.  The input (result) is an array of file names that exist on an S3 bucket.  What I'm hoping to do is loop through that list and retrieve a signed URL for each one.

```html
let result = [{ fileName: "dog.jpg" },{ fileName: "cat.jpg"}];

async function getSignedUrl(key){
    let params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key };
    let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      return url;
    });
}

async function process(items) {
  for (let item of items) {
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(item.fileName);
    item.url = signedUrl;
  }
  return items;
}


process(result).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

The problem is when I console.log the result, the new URL isn't present.  I can't figure out what the problem is.  I'm guessing it's an async issue but I'm not experienced enough to figure it out.

Comment: You ONLY use `await` with a function that returns a promise, not a function that takes a callback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let result = [{ fileName: "dog.jpg" },{ fileName: "cat.jpg"}];

async function getSignedUrl(key){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      let params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key };
      s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(url);
      });
});
}

async function process(items) {
  for (let item of items) {
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(item.fileName);
    item.url = signedUrl;
  }
  return items;
}


process(result).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

NOTE: it's better to use `Promise.all()` if you are processing an array of possible promises since `await` stops the execution of that code in ***async function*** **(not the event loop)** even though it's a none blocker function. Doing parallel request is much faster in this scenario

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It helped me a lot.  

I just had to remove the 'await' in let url = await s3.getSignedUrl to get it working.  

I'll try to implement it with Promise.all() later.

Comment: oh yeah.. I forgot to remove the await.. thanks for pointing that.

Comment: The docs seem to say the getObject version of getSignedUrl is synchronous https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property Why is it necessary to await synchronous code?